# Trying to filter dataGridView with combobox, error : "There is already an open DataReader"

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have 2 tables. One is :

Table A(

idA

name)

FK numB(

Table B

idB

CityName)

I am trying to filter a dataGridView of the Table A with a CityName from a combobox.

In my combobox properties :

- DataSource = TableB BindingSource
- DisplayMember = CityName
- ValueMember = idB
- SelectedValue = SpectacleBindingSource.numB

Then the code i am trying to go with  :

```
        private void cbGenreB_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int value = 0;


        if (cbGenreB.SelectedIndex !=-1)
        {
            compare = (cbGenreB.SelectedIndex);

            this.ATableAdapter.FillByCityB(this.billetterieDataSet.A, compare);
        }
```

There is no problem with the select request, then i got this error message :

http://gyazo.com/1bb7b1792c3dce676b257245bbb72e97

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

A best practice with ADO.NET is to always close the DataReader when you are finished reading the data. If the Connection you are using is only used to return the DataReader, close it immediately after closing the DataReader.

You can use a DataSet to store all rows or create another connection to avoid this problem.

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx